# C++ boolean infinite loop

Tags: c++, winapi

so I've got this code:

```
bool toggl = false;
while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT)) {
        if (toggl) {
            toggl = false;
            std::cout << "Off" << std::endl;

        }
        else {
            toggl = true;
            std::cout << "On" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I click insert it just creates a infinite loop changing from false to true. When I use `break` my whole window just closes.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Ossie

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: _".. .and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down,"_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate  You need to do some bit testing just use the result as a `bool`.

Comment: Note that it is normally not a good idea to busy-wait for a keypress. This will cause 100% CPU usage on one CPU while waiting for the keypress, preventing other tasks from using that CPU and also increasing power usage. Instead, you should normally suspend your process while waiting for keypresses, for example by calling [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage), and then respond to [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and `WM_KEYUP` events.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation for GetAsyncKeyState: "If the function succeeds, the return value specifies whether the key was pressed since the last call to GetAsyncKeyState, and whether the key is currently up or down. If the most significant bit is set, the key is down, and if the least significant bit is set, the key was pressed after the previous call to GetAsyncKeyState."

```
hi               lo
1000 0000 0000 0001
^                 ^
|                 |
|                 pressed since last call
key down (0 for up)
```

For the infinite loop you only need to have the key state be non-zero.  Better tests...

```
0 != (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) & 1) // pressed since last call
0 != (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) & 0x8000) // key down
```

The same documentation warns about use of this last bit for mouse clicks and when other processes are using GetAsyncKeyState at the same time.  Worth reading.

Current URL to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when `insert` is tapped, your program will have looped on GetAsyncKeyState 20 or 30 times.  And then your `toggl` flag is getting flipped each time.  Hence, a new print statement.

I suspect this is what you really want:

```
bool toggl = false;
while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {

    bool isInsertDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) != 0);

    if (toggl && !isInsertDown)
    {
        toggl = false;
        std::cout << "Off" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (!toggl && isInsertDown)
    {
        toggl = true;
        std::cout << "On" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above will flip the `togl` state to `true` when the `insert` key is down, and set it back to `false` when you lift your finger off the key.

But if you want to have `toggl` state changed on individual key presses. That is, first `insert` tap sets `toggl` to true and the next key press sets it back to `false`, then you'll need another variable.  Hence:

```
bool toggl = false;
bool lastWasDown = false;
while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {

    bool isInsertDown = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) != 0;

    if (isInsertDown == lastWasDown) {
        continue;
    }

    if (isInsertDown && !toggl) {
        toggl = true;
        std::cout << "On" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (isInsertDown && toggl) {
        toggl = false;
        std::cout << "Off" << std::endl;
    }

    lastWasDown = isInsertDown;
}
```